# Pandas DataFrame Cross-Reference/Selective Join/Overlay?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

What is the best/fastest way to do a selective lookup/cross-reference/overlay/partial join between two Pandas DataFrames? I'm not sure of the right terminology to use....

Given:

1. A primary table filled with numerical values and some arbitrary lookup/reference strings, indexed by date/month
2. A secondary table, with a consistent index to the first. Columns of this dataframe match with the arbitrary lookup/reference strings in the primary table which can change over time, and serve as the lookup column to replace values in the primary table.

The indices of the two tables don't necessarily need to be exactly the same set (or even contiguous), but if a lookup is present in **Table 1** it obviously needs a corresponding row in **Table 2**.

i.e. I'd like to find every lookup/placeholder in **Table 1** and replace with the correct lookup value in **Table 2** from the correct month.

Example below:

**Table 1**

| dte | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-02 | 3 | LOOKUP1 |
| 2022-03 | LOOKUP3 | 4 |
| 2022-04 | 5 | 6 |

**Table 2**

| dte | LOOKUP1 | LOOKUP2 | LOOKUP3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12 | 101 | 105 | 109 |
| 2022-02 | 102 | 106 | 110 |
| 2022-03 | 103 | 107 | 111 |
| 2022-10 | 104 | 108 | 112 |

**Result**

| dte | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-02 | 3 | 102 |
| 2022-03 | 111 | 4 |
| 2022-04 | 5 | 6 |

I need to do a pile of these in my use case, so was hoping for something at least reasonably fast. I'm not an expert with Pandas, wondering if there is a smart way to do this. I could loop through every row/column in **Table 1**, look for values that match column names in **Table 2** and then do a lookup in **Table 2** replacing value in **Table 1**. There seems to often be a smart way to do this kind of thing in Pandas where it automatically paralellizes for you. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is using replace , not sure about the speed

```
out = tb1.set_index('dte').T.replace(tb2.set_index('dte').T).T
Out[172]: 
        value1 value2
dte                  
2022-01      1      2
2022-02      3    102
2022-03    111      4
2022-04      5      6
```

Comment: I can't believe the pandas `replace` function is this smart. If it's built-in to pandas like this I'm sure it is fast enough for me. Let me have a quick check of this.

Comment: Yep this does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! How are these Pandas people so smart....